# tomcat 8.5.x tomcat-jdbc.jar vs official oracle ojdbc6.jar driver

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, ojdbc

I'm struggling with jdbc connection to oracle database, which should I use?
The **tomcat-jdbc.jar** (inside tomcat) or **oracle ojdbc6.jar** (official by oracle)
What are the difference between the two driver?
(ojdbc6 version 11.2.0.4 guarantee to me to work with oracle 12c db and oracle 10 db could do the same the tomcat-jdbc.jar??)

Comment: You should use  **oracle ojdbc6.jar**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, they are different libraries. **tomcat-jdbc.jar** is the default Tomcat connection pool (in Tomcat version 8.5) and it's responsible for managing connections, allowing you fast access to already created ones, whereas **ojdbc6.jar** is your actual JDBC driver from Oracle that provides database connectivity to Oracle Database server. 
Other words, you cannot use **tomcat-jdbc.jar** alone in case you want to "talk" to your Oracle Database, but it's possible to use **ojdbc6.jar** without pooling, although it's not recommended due to perfomance drop in most cases.

Here is a good explanation:

- ojdbc6.jar -
  [What is ojdbc6.jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31363047/what-is-ojdbc6-jar-file)
- Connection Pool - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool